# Parse NSPredicate with nil option for finding any object

Tags: parse-platform

I have tried to search the web, and didn't came across any subject regarding default fallbacks for NSPredicate driven queries.

For instance I want to query some jokes by some category.

So I got this little helper method:

```
- (PFQuery)queryJokesWithCategory:(PFObject *)category language:(NSString *)language {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language = %@ AND category = %@", language, category];
    PFQuery *jokes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Joke" predicate:predicate];
    return jokes;
}
```

If I pass nil for the category I would expect to get all jokes, but it doesn't give me a single. Like this:

```
PFQuery *jokesQuery = [self queryForJokesWithCategory:nil language:@"EN"];
```

Are there any ways to do it like my approach? any keywords specific I have missed?

Comment: So you just want to get jokes that are in language "EN," but not in a certain category, correct?

Comment: Eventually yes. It's just if the category is set to none, then there is no need to query for category = this OR category = that. Not that I have any intention doing that. I would just dynamically check for nil. Just wondered if there was an easier approach

Comment: Each joke DOES have a category, yes? There is no joke in the data browser with an undefined category?

Comment: Yes each joke has a category. If nothing suits it will go under "misc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do in this situation is check if the "category" key exists, and in your case, it always will, so you could run this query:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language = %@ AND category IN SELF", language];
PFQuery *jokes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Joke" predicate:predicate];
return jokes;
```

This query will query the Joke table for all jokes with the specified language, disregarding the category, only ensuring that it is defined.

EDIT:

I don't know how your app works, but it sounds like the user needs to enter a category and a language, and then you want to construct a query based on their entry. You would have to check to see if their field for category was empty, and then do the query I posted above, and if it wasn't empty, use the original query. I don't think you can accomplish this in one query, though.

As another suggestion, maybe make the category field mandatory, or just have a "View all" button to view all jokes under the selected language.

Comment: How do I use this to query for jokes in the 'animal' category for instance? For me it looks like this just ensures that a category exists

Comment: @Chrene Well I don't know how your app works, but it sounds like the user needs to enter a category and a language, and then you want to construct a query based on their entry. You would have to check to see if their field for category was empty, and then do the query I posted above, and if it wasn't empty, use the original query. I don't think you can accomplish this in one query, though.

Comment: Too bad though. Well update your answer with what you said and I'll accept that. :) thanks for your time of course

Comment: @Chrene Thanks, appreciate it! Good luck!